# (VHDL) Two components in top level entity but only one working

Tags: vhdl, intel, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I am programming in VHDL 1993 under QUARTUS II, and I just created two components in order to try solve the problem I am about to present as they weren't the solution. Before hand, the components files are included in the design and working one at a time.

So in my basic application I am trying to do two jobs, one is to blink a led and to turn on another led controlled by a switch, when I declare both components only the one controlling the led with the switch works, then when I undeclared the led-switch component and it's signals IN THE TOP LEVEL ENTITY the blinker works, I am guessing then it's a problem with the signal declarations at the top level entity "test2", but I don't understand why it works only when using one thing at a time, what I coded at the top level entity is:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity test2 is
    port(   clk_cpu, K2: in std_logic;
            led1, led2: out std_logic);
end test2;

architecture struct of test2 is

    component tmp_toogler
        port(   clk: in std_logic;
            led: out std_logic);
    end component;

    component yes_driver
        port(   input: in std_logic;
            output: out std_logic);
    end component;

begin

    instanciaD: yes_driver PORT MAP(
        K2, led2
    );

    instancia1: tmp_toogler PORT MAP(
        clk_cpu, led1
    );

end struct;
```

The blinker component:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity tmp_toogler is
    port(   clk: in std_logic;
            led: out std_logic);
end tmp_toogler;

architecture struct of tmp_toogler is

signal counter: integer range 0 to 50000000;
signal state : std_logic := '1';

begin
    process(clk)

    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        counter <= counter + 1;
        end if;

        if(counter = 50000000) then
        counter <= 0;
            if(state = '0') then 
            led <= '1';
            state <= '1';
            else
            led <= '0';
            state <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end struct;
```

The led-switch:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity yes_driver is
    port(   input: in std_logic;
            output: out std_logic);
end yes_driver;

architecture struct of yes_driver is
begin
    process(input)
    begin
    output <= input;
    end process;
end struct;
```

I feel this is a very basic question about doing multiple tasks, so I am urging for some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: tmp_toogler has an asynchronous reset for counter combinatorially produced, it's also used to toggle state (and led).  You could operated the reset synchronously and make state a register instead of a latch, avoiding static hazards. Otherwise your circuit simulates. Your readers may not be able to replicate the issue without identical synthesis target and tools and configuration.

Comment: Try declaring ports 1 per line.